# How do you set permissions on a network directory for sharepoint access?

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, web-parts, user-accounts, folder-permissions

I have created a visual web part and placed it in my sharepoint site.

This web part accesses and displays data from an excel file on my network, an example directory is `\\server1\files\file.xls`

I can get this to work by applying read access to 'everyone' in the domain.

I want to lock this file down so only the sharepoint site can access this data, and everyone else unable to access it outside of the sharepoint site.

My question here is basically: what default user account on my domain does sharepoint use?

If i can find this out, i can apply read permissions to this account without having to apply it to all users.

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: Why are you using network directory instead of sharepoint list?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to apply read permissions to the account that is used as application pool identity for your SharePoint web application. You can find this account in IIS Manager.

Comment: Click on the web site for which you want to check the App pool identity, then click on the "Advanced Settings" in right pane. There you can see the name of the application pool for that web application.
Now go to "Application Pools" in the left tree view and there, in the Identity column you can see the the user.